# Trigger UPDATE() and COLUMNS_UPDATED() functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have AFTER UPDATE trigger on table.

I need to get the name of changing colomn and it's old and new values.

To do statement `UPDATE(column_name)` with each column in code - bad solution. But I can't get all table colomns names via query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'smth'
```

and in cursor dynamically get `UPDATE(@column_name)` value.

At same time when I try to use `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` function when I update only one column in table, I have results (value converted to int):

```
64 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 31)
32 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 30)
8 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 29)
4 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 28)
2 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 27)
1 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 26)
32768 (Updated column with ORDINAL_POSITION = 25)
```

I think it is very strange and ask your help.

Comment: How do you convert the result of `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` to `int`, please?

Answer (score 5):

Whether it is strange or not, this is at least [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx):

> **Caution**
>
> In SQL Server 2008, the ORDINAL_POSITION column of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view is not compatible with the bit pattern of columns returned by COLUMNS_UPDATED. To obtain a bit pattern compatible with COLUMNS_UPDATED, reference the ColumnID property of the COLUMNPROPERTY system function when you query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,
>     COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME),
>     COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') AS COLUMN_ID
> FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Contact';
> ```

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE() will return true if the column is referenced, it doesn't matter if the value hasn't changed

so if you do

```
update table BLa
set Col1 = Col1
```

in the trigger UPDATE() will return true for that column

join `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables in the trigger and check that the values haven't changed also make sure to account for NULLs of course....

Comment: Is the reference existence also returning true for `COLUMNS_UPDATED()`?